# webcontainer in Websphere vs tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, websphere

In a conversation, somebody asked me "let us say our web application only needs JSP/Servlets (no EJB), then in which case would you prefer websphere over tomcat server".
Here was my response that if our application need following features of websphere :-
i)if app requires Websphere provides clustering and fail-over mechanism. 
ii) if app requires Websphere services like caching, JMS and Security services.
iii) if app need to interact with third party system/resource using JCA protocol
iv) if organisation is not cormfortable on putting their app on open-source based server

I want to validate my understanding above..and does any body have any extra points?

Answer (score 1):

Answers "i", "ii" and "iii" are not entirely relevant. True, WebSphere's support for clustering and fail-over is very good out-of-the-box, and it also has caching, JMS, security and JCA support out of the box - but by using third-party products (also open-source) as add-ons to Tomcat, you can get these functionalities on Tomcat as well.

Answer "iv"'s relevance depends on whether the asker was talking about technicalities only. True, certain organizations are indeed not comfortable running their applications on open-source software; usually, these are organizations that tend to involve politics with technical decisions. There are many political factors that I won't get into here, but remember - these are political, rather than technical, factors.

In short: if all you need is JSP/Servlets, using WebSphere is a waste, mostly of money. If you need a bit extra over JSP/Servlets, use an open-source application server (Apache Geronimo, for example) or even JBoss. WebSphere is too expensive to do anything with, unless your organization insists on paying (a lot of money) for application servers due to political (or other non-technical) reasons.

Comment: thanks Issac. So from your experience on websphere, you don't see any additional benefit on choosing websphere over tomcat server or for that matter over other open source app server?

Comment: Wow, this is old... sorry I haven't seen this comment. Well, as I said, it really depends on your requirements. WebSphere is as feature-ful as it is expensive. For JSP/Servlet only work, WebSphere is definitely an overkill. There's no reason to pay significant amount of money for functionality that is readily-available, for free, through the open source software community. I'm not saying that WebSphere is not a good product; it is. But factoring in costs, it might not be the best choice overall.